# Customize Ektron HTML Form Email Layout

Tags: html, forms, email, ektron

I would like to know if there's a way to customize the email HTML body contents when submitting an Ektron HTML form.

For example, a form is submitted and the form data is emailed to john@doe.gov. Upon opening the email, there is a table containing the data from the submitted form. I want to know if there's a way to modify the HTML table which was generated for that email.

My goal is to experiment with some CSS to force word-wrapping in the table so lengthy textarea-input data will be wrapped appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never tried customizing it, so I don't know if there are any "gotchas", but these files look promising:

- /Workarea/controls/forms/DefaultFormEmailBody.xslt
- /Workarea/controls/forms/template_FormDataDisplay.xslt
- /Workarea/controls/forms/template_FormFieldValue.xslt

The table is generated in "template_FormDataDisplay.xslt", and the individual table rows are generated in "template_FormFieldValue.xslt".

The usual "I want to modify something in the workarea" warning applies: **Make backups of any file you change, and know that installing an upgrade to Ektron will overwrite any of your changes.**

Comment: Those are the exact files I need. I've been playing with it for awhile now. It seems I can just modify these files, test a form, and the modifications are present in the email. Now I need to learn about email HTML and CSS. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using php? Because you can edit the way that email looks once you open it. This is an awesome tutorial:

http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-create-a-contact-form-using-html5-css3-and-php/

Comment: I believe Ektron uses .net, but I'm not sure where to find the existing code that generates the HTML table for the email, or if I even have access to the code that does so.

Comment: Ektron is ASP.NET and C#, with a few .NET services that run on the server, so PHP wouldn't apply here.  The files you are looking for are likely in the /Workarea/ folder structure.